# How to return childobject property from json with lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am using lodash and have this json object, the property I would like to return is a nested array ie swappableProducts:

```
{
  "existing": {
    "hasPlatinum": false,
    "primaryBundle": {
      "id": "2008",
      "serviceId": "1",
      "name": "TV - Entertainment, Sport",
      "products": [
        {
          "name": "Entertainment",
          "id": "100",
          "price": 2600,
          "gifted": false
        },
        {
          "name": "Sport",
          "id": "107",
          "price": 2500,
          "gifted": false,
          "swappableProducts": [
            {
              "name": "Movies",
              "id": "105",
              "price": 2000,
              "gifted": false
            },
            {
              "name": "Games",
              "id": "10",
              "price": 1000,
              "gifted": false
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I tried to return the swappableProducts array like this:

```
 _.get(userObject, 'existing.primaryBundle.products[1].swappableProducts');
```

but it won't return it. How can I do this?

Comment: Why not `var arrayReference = userObject.existing.products[1].swappableProducts`?

Comment: not sure what the problem is but that works just fine for me? Did you try to `console.log` it

Comment: That's working fine except one closing curly braces is missing in the JSON object, which should be a typo, I assume